# Change Image on Check Box Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, checkbox, selected

I am building a site that will give users a preview of their selection (image).

As it stands now, both individual functions work, but its a bit confusing because, the checkbox does one thing, but they have to click the image to change the preview. Here' the code:

```
$(".checkbox_collar").change(function(){                        
                    $('.tile_collar').css('border', 'none');
                    $(this).closest('td').find('.tile_collar').css('border', "solid 1px #FC810A"); 
                });
                $('.optionsTable').delegate('img','click', function(){
                    $('#preview_image').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('tile','preview'));
                });
```

I want to the preview image (#preview_image) to change on the checkbox change (.checkbox_collar)

Here is my attempted solution, that didn't work (to give a better idea of what I am trying to do:

```
$(".checkbox_<?=$tabOption?>").change(function(){                       
                    $('.tile_collar').css('border', 'none');
                    $(this).closest('td').find('.tile_collar').css('border', "solid 1px #FC810A");
                    $('#preview_image').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('tile','preview')); 
                });
```

The above didn't work... is there any way to tie the two together? So that when the user clicks... it adds the border and changes pic in $preview_image?

Better yet, is there way to have the tile image check the box if clicked?

By popular domand (lol), I have added som HTML; sorry for any inconvenience:

```
<table class="optionsTable" id="optionsTable">
                            <tr>
                                <td><img src="img/option/tile/test.png" width="100px" class="tile_test" style="border: solid 1px #FC810A">
                                    <br>
                                    <input class="checkbox" id="optionRadio" type="radio" name="test" value="1" checked="checked">
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            </table>  
                    </div><!--option div-->
                    <div id="option_preview">

                        <img src="img/option/preview/test.png" width="335px" alt="test">
                        <div id="option_desc" class="option_desc">Edit</div>
```

Update here is an update to my code that gets the box to wokr but won't check the check box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            $('#optionsTable_<?=$tabOption?>').delegate('img','click', function(){
                                $('.tile_<?=$tabOption?>').css('border', 'none');
                                $(this).closest('td').find('.tile_<?=$tabOption?>').css('border', "solid 1px #FC810A");
                                $('#preview_<?=$optionSku?>').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('tile','preview')); 
                           });
                        </script>
```

Comment: Post some of your HTML or better yet, put this on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$(".checkbox_collar").on('change', function(){
   var newSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('tile','preview');
   $('#preview_image').attr('src', newSrc);

   $(this).next('td').find('.tile_collar').css('border', '1px solid red');
});
```

But the example should show some HTML.

Alright, I think I get what you are trying to do.  Check out this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/kDeFQ/

I've cleaned up your implementation.  This seems to work, but you might need to mess with the replace method.  Also, I've removed your funky selectors, you might try putting those back.  You should probably break this down into discrete parts.  The onChange event should call its own method.  Good luck!

```
<div>
    <table class="optionsTable" id="optionsTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="/img/oneimage.gif" width="100px" class="tile_test" style="border: solid 1px #FC810A">
                <input class="checkbox" id="optionRadio" type="checkbox" name="test" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div><!--option div-->

<div id="option_preview">
    <img src="/img/otherimage.png" width="335px" alt="test">
    <div id="option_desc" class="option_desc">Edit</div>
</div>


<script>
    $('#optionsTable input.checkbox').on('change', function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        $('.tile_'+ name ).css('border', 'none');
        $(this).prev('td').find('.tile_' + name).css('border', "solid 1px #FC810A");

        //now get src
        var source = $(this).prev('img').attr('src');
            source = source.replace('title', 'preview');
        console.log(source);
        $('#option_preview img').attr('src', source);
    });
</script>
```